# How can I remove active class on click on a tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list that when `<a>` element is clicked it changes the color. Now I need when other sibiling `<a>` is clicked it should remove the active class and add it to the clicked one.

```js
$( function() {
      $('a').click( function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("selected").siblings().removeClass('selected');
      });
});
```

```css
.selected {
     color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"/>
<ul>
 <li>
  <a>First</a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a>Second</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I know that the code will work if I add `.selected` class to the `li` but I need to achieve it with the `<a>` tag. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. On click remove the selected class from all a then add that class to the clicked one

```js
$('a').click(function() {
  $('a').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');

});
```

```css
.selected {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a>First</a></li>
  <li><a>Second</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It works here but in my case on my website when I add the .removeClass it wont work. Do you know why is that happening?

Comment: Oh figured it out, I was using this to the removeClass $, that was the problem. All good now thanks!

Comment: @FreelancerHelp glad to help happy coding mate